# WooCommerce - Add to Cart Link with Sale Price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the add to cart link function in Woocommerce and I was wondering if there is a way when using the Add to cart link you can have it where it adds the sale price to the cart rather than the standard price.

I would like the price to stay at the normal price on their product's page but in other places when I use the add to cart link which when clicked would add the sale price to the cart.

```
href=”https://yourdomain.com/?add-to-cart=25″
```

I'm not sure if there is a parameter that I can add to the link which would add the sale price of the ID product 25 to the cart rather then the standard price.
Thank you

Comment: **1/2** _"I'm not sure if there is a parameter that I can add to the link which would add the sale price of the ID product 25 to the cart rather then the standard price"_ 
- Not by default. You can of course always provide it yourself via custom code. The only problem I see with this is that a 'security' would be needed. Namely, you have certain products where you do use that url, and other products where you don't. What prevents a customer from 'reproducing' the url for the products where this is not the case so that the customer can buy all products at a lower price.

Comment: **2/2** It is possible.. taking into account what I have just described. I rather see as a solution, that when the product is added in the cart, you automatically adjust the price at that time to the price you want... instead of doing this via the url